# How do I scrape the table from a website (link provided) using CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, css-tables

Here's the website I need to extract some election data from: http://www.bradleyelections.com/results/html/BradleyPrecSumm01.htm

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>PrecinctSummary</title>
</head>
<style type='text/css'>
.s0_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:9.75pt;}
.s1_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:197.5pt;}
.s2_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:45pt;}
.s3_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:57.75pt;}
.s4_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:24pt;}
.s5_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:15pt;}
.s6_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:0pt;}
.s7_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:16.5pt;}
.s8_    {position:relative;width:540.75pt;height:4.5pt;}
.s9_    {position:relative;width:577.5pt;height:0.25pt;}
.s10_   {position:relative;width:577.5pt;height:97.5pt;}
.s11_   {position:relative;width:577.5pt;height:0pt;}
.s12_   {position:relative;width:577.5pt;height:0pt;}
.s13_   {position:relative;width:577.5pt;height:0pt;}
.s14_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:15pt;}
.s15_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:18pt;}
.s16_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:0pt;}
.s17_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:0pt;}
.s18_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:0pt;}
.s19_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:35.25pt;}
.s20_   {position:relative;width:468pt;height:0pt;}
.f0_    {position:absolute;left:310.5pt;top:4.5pt;width:220.5pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;}
.f1_    {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:0pt;width:43.5pt;height:8.25pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f2_    {position:absolute;left:63pt;top:0pt;width:43.5pt;height:8.25pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f3_    {position:absolute;left:115.5pt;top:0pt;width:48pt;height:9pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f4_    {position:absolute;left:310.5pt;top:0pt;width:220.5pt;height:9pt;font:8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;vertical-align:middle;}
.f5_    {position:absolute;left:464.25pt;top:4.5pt;width:25.5pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f6_    {position:absolute;left:508.5pt;top:4.5pt;width:25.5pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f7_    {position:absolute;left:135pt;top:4.5pt;width:58.5pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f8_    {position:absolute;left:27pt;top:135pt;width:504pt;height:59.25pt;font:8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;}
.f9_    {position:absolute;left:18pt;top:24pt;width:220.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';line-height:10.14pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f10_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:56.25pt;width:522pt;height:1pt;font:0pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;border-top:solid Black 0.5pt;z-index:1;}
.f11_   {position:absolute;left:190.5pt;top:42.75pt;width:33pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f12_   {position:absolute;left:276pt;top:42.75pt;width:13.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f13_   {position:absolute;left:334.5pt;top:41.25pt;width:97.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f14_   {position:absolute;left:489pt;top:42pt;width:46.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f15_   {position:absolute;left:490.5pt;top:4.5pt;width:16.5pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f16_   {position:absolute;left:175.5pt;top:0pt;width:48pt;height:9pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f17_   {position:absolute;left:240pt;top:0pt;width:48pt;height:9pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f18_   {position:absolute;left:90pt;top:4.5pt;width:45pt;height:9pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;}
.f19_   {position:absolute;left:310.5pt;top:0pt;width:121.5pt;height:13.5pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f20_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:4.5pt;width:252pt;height:40.5pt;font:8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;}
.f21_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:13.5pt;width:522pt;height:1pt;font:0pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;border-top:solid Black 0.5pt;z-index:1;}
.f22_   {position:absolute;left:310.5pt;top:13.5pt;width:220.5pt;height:1pt;font:0pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;border-top:solid Black 0.5pt;z-index:1;}
.f23_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:9pt;width:364.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 9.8pt 'Arial';line-height:10.99pt;vertical-align:middle;}
.f24_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:0pt;width:522pt;height:1pt;font:0pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;border-top:solid Black 0.5pt;z-index:1;}
.f25_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:13.5pt;width:504pt;height:27pt;font:bold 18pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f26_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:13.5pt;width:126pt;height:15pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f27_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:40.5pt;width:531pt;height:3pt;font:3pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;background:Black;}
.f28_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:45pt;width:468pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 12pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f29_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:63pt;width:468pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 12pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f30_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:81pt;width:468pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 12pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f31_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:99pt;width:468pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 12pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f32_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:117pt;width:531pt;height:3pt;font:3pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;background:Black;}
.f33_   {position:absolute;left:497.25pt;top:0pt;width:22.5pt;height:22.5pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;}
.f34_   {position:absolute;left:495pt;top:22.5pt;width:27pt;height:15pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f35_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt;width:216pt;height:13.5pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f36_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt;width:144pt;height:13.5pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;}
.f37_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:13.5pt;width:270pt;height:9pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;}
.f38_   {position:absolute;left:315pt;top:0pt;width:216pt;height:13.5pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;}
.f39_   {position:absolute;left:297pt;top:13.5pt;width:234pt;height:9pt;font:9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;}
.f40_   {position:absolute;left:9pt;top:0pt;width:522pt;height:1pt;font:0pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;border-top:solid Black 0.5pt;z-index:1;}
.f41_   {position:absolute;left:39pt;top:42.75pt;width:13.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f42_   {position:absolute;left:93pt;top:42.75pt;width:13.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f43_   {position:absolute;left:150pt;top:42.75pt;width:13.5pt;height:15pt;font:bold 8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.f44_   {position:absolute;left:94.5pt;top:58.5pt;width:90pt;height:12pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f45_   {position:absolute;left:94.5pt;top:76.5pt;width:90pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f46_   {position:absolute;left:185.25pt;top:27pt;width:54pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f47_   {position:absolute;left:185.25pt;top:13.5pt;width:54pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f48_   {position:absolute;left:185.25pt;top:0pt;width:54pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f49_   {position:absolute;left:184.5pt;top:58.5pt;width:54pt;height:12pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f50_   {position:absolute;left:184.5pt;top:76.5pt;width:54pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f51_   {position:absolute;left:270pt;top:0pt;width:100.5pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f52_   {position:absolute;left:370.5pt;top:0pt;width:95.25pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f53_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt;width:185.25pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f54_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:13.5pt;width:185.25pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';line-height:10.14pt;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f55_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:27pt;width:185.25pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';line-height:10.14pt;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f56_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:4.5pt;width:54pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f57_   {position:absolute;left:54pt;top:4.5pt;width:63pt;height:13.5pt;font:bold 9pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
.f58_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:22.5pt;width:103.5pt;height:12.75pt;font:bold 10pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:Gainsboro;}
.f59_   {position:absolute;left:103.5pt;top:22.5pt;width:108pt;height:12.75pt;font:bold 10pt 'Times New Roman';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:Gainsboro;}
.f60_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt;width:103.5pt;height:15pt;font:8pt 'Arial';line-height:9.02pt;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f61_   {position:absolute;left:103.5pt;top:0pt;width:108pt;height:15pt;font:8pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;padding:0pt 3pt;border:solid Black 0.5pt;background:White;}
.f62_   {position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt;width:184.5pt;height:18pt;font:bold 12pt 'Arial';overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;}
</style>
<body>
<div class=s1_ style="height:236pt;">
<span class=f25_>Precinct Summary Report</span>
<span class=f35_>11/4/2014 - 8:42:30 PM</span>
<span class=f33_><img src='Bradley_PrecSumm_01_files/PrecinctSummary_Field10_pic0.png' style='position:absolute;left:0pt;top:0pt'></span>
<span class=f26_>Election Date: 11/4/2014</span>
<span class=f34_>EMS</span>
<span class=f27_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f28_>Bradley County, Tennessee</span>
<span class=f29_>2014 General Election</span>
<span class=f30_>TNBRAG14</span>
<span class=f31_>11/4/2014</span>
<span class=f32_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f53_ style="left:27pt;top:135pt;">E - # Of Election Day Votes</span>
<span class=f48_ style="left:212.25pt;top:135pt;">405</span>
<span class=f51_ style="left:297pt;top:135pt;">PRECINCT STATUS:</span>
<span class=f52_ style="left:397.55pt;top:135pt;">INCOMPLETE</span>
<span class=f54_ style="left:27pt;top:148.55pt;">A - # Of Absentee and Early Votes</span>
<span class=f47_ style="left:212.25pt;top:148.55pt;">319</span>
<span class=f55_ style="left:27pt;top:162pt;">P - # Of Provisional Votes</span>
<span class=f46_ style="left:212.25pt;top:162pt;">0</span>
<span class=f44_ style="left:121.55pt;top:193.55pt;">&nbsp;PUBLIC COUNT:</span>
<span class=f49_ style="left:211.55pt;top:193.55pt;">724</span>
<span class=f45_ style="left:121.55pt;top:211.55pt;">&nbsp;VOTER TURNOUT:</span>
<span class=f50_ style="left:211.55pt;top:211.55pt;">33.58%</span>
</div>
<div class=s3_>
<span class=f23_>01-McDonald</span>
<span class=f9_>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - VOTES - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
<span class=f13_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f14_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f41_>E</span>
<span class=f42_>A</span>
<span class=f43_>P</span>
<span class=f11_>TOTAL</span>
<span class=f12_>%</span>
<span class=f10_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>694</span>
<span class=f0_>Governor</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>335</span>
<span class=f2_>252</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>587</span>
<span class=f17_>84.58%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Bill Haslam (R)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>39</span>
<span class=f2_>37</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>76</span>
<span class=f17_>10.95%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Charles V. &quot;Charlie&quot; Brown (D)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>5</span>
<span class=f2_>5</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>10</span>
<span class=f17_>1.44%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Shaun Crowell (C)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>2</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>2</span>
<span class=f17_>0.29%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Isa Infante (G)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>4</span>
<span class=f2_>2</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>6</span>
<span class=f17_>0.86%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Steven Damon Coburn (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>5</span>
<span class=f2_>3</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>8</span>
<span class=f17_>1.15%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">John Jay Hooker (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>3</span>
<span class=f2_>2</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>5</span>
<span class=f17_>0.72%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Daniel T. Lewis (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Write-In</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>695</span>
<span class=f0_>Constitutional Amendment # 1</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>271</span>
<span class=f2_>213</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>484</span>
<span class=f17_>69.64%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Yes</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>116</span>
<span class=f2_>95</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>211</span>
<span class=f17_>30.36%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">No</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>698</span>
<span class=f0_>Constitutional Amendment # 2</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>269</span>
<span class=f2_>216</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>485</span>
<span class=f17_>69.48%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Yes</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>122</span>
<span class=f2_>91</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>213</span>
<span class=f17_>30.52%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">No</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>671</span>
<span class=f0_>Constitutional Amendment # 3</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>282</span>
<span class=f2_>227</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>509</span>
<span class=f17_>75.86%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Yes</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>93</span>
<span class=f2_>69</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>162</span>
<span class=f17_>24.14%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">No</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>660</span>
<span class=f0_>Constitutional Amendment # 4</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>272</span>
<span class=f2_>210</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>482</span>
<span class=f17_>73.03%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Yes</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>104</span>
<span class=f2_>74</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>178</span>
<span class=f17_>26.97%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">No</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>706</span>
<span class=f0_>United States Senate</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>321</span>
<span class=f2_>243</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>564</span>
<span class=f17_>79.89%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Lamar Alexander (R)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>56</span>
<span class=f2_>49</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>105</span>
<span class=f17_>14.87%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Gordon Ball (D)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>10</span>
<span class=f2_>5</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>15</span>
<span class=f17_>2.12%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Joe Wilmoth (C)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>2</span>
<span class=f2_>2</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>4</span>
<span class=f17_>0.57%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Martin Pleasant (G)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>4</span>
<span class=f2_>6</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>10</span>
<span class=f17_>1.42%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Tom Emerson, Jr. (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Edmund L. Gauthier (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Joshua James (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>2</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>2</span>
<span class=f17_>0.28%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Danny Page (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>1</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>1</span>
<span class=f17_>0.14%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Bartholomew J. Phillips (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">C. Salekin (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Eric Schechter (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>4</span>
<span class=f2_>1</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>5</span>
<span class=f17_>0.71%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Rick Tyler (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>0</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>0</span>
<span class=f17_>0.00%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Write-In</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>678</span>
<span class=f0_>US House 4th Cong Dist</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>278</span>
<span class=f2_>196</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>474</span>
<span class=f17_>69.91%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Scott Desjarlais (R)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>76</span>
<span class=f2_>73</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>149</span>
<span class=f17_>21.98%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Lenda Sherrell (D)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>30</span>
<span class=f2_>24</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>54</span>
<span class=f17_>7.96%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Robert Rankin Doggart (I)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>0</span>
<span class=f2_>1</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>1</span>
<span class=f17_>0.15%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Write-In</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>631</span>
<span class=f0_>TN House 24th Rep District</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>353</span>
<span class=f2_>262</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>615</span>
<span class=f17_>97.46%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Kevin D. Brooks (R)</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>8</span>
<span class=f2_>8</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>16</span>
<span class=f17_>2.54%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Write-In</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s5_>
<span class=f40_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f19_>VOTE FOR 1</span>
<span class=f5_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f15_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f6_>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=f21_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s7_>
<span class=f18_>VOTES=</span>
<span class=f7_>30</span>
<span class=f0_>Cleveland Wine at Retail Stores</span>
<span class=f22_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>3</span>
<span class=f2_>13</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>16</span>
<span class=f17_>53.33%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">For Wine In Stores</span>
</div>
<div class=s0_ style="height:10.23pt;">
<span class=f1_>8</span>
<span class=f2_>6</span>
<span class=f3_>0</span>
<span class=f16_>14</span>
<span class=f17_>46.67%</span>
<span class=f4_ style="height:9.45pt;">Against Wine In Stores</span>
</div>
<div class=s8_>
</div>
<div class=s2_>
<span class=f24_>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class=s4_>
<span class=f36_>Precinct Summary Report</span>
<span class=f38_>11/4/2014 - 8:42:30 PM</span>
<span class=f37_>2014 General Election [Election Date: 11/4/2014]</span>
<span class=f39_>Page 1 of 1</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm familar with how HTML Tables work but I don't recognize the syntax in the source code. I presume it is CSS, but that still leaves the question of how to get this table into an Excel or CSV format in an automated way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't scrape with CSS. Most likely you'll need to use a server side language like PHP (probably with CURL) and then process it with a DOM library or some string methods (like regular expressions). By scraping the data you'll completely ignore the CSS.

Comment: Site is down => unclear what you're asking

Comment: @ArtjomB. They have renamed the files on that site. Here is the updated link: http://www.bradleyelections.com/results/html/Bradley_PrecSumm_01.htm

Comment: @ankit Please include the markup in the question itself, so that this Q&A doesn't lose all value if the link goes dark again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a table, it's just span elements. I believe you are confusing HTML/CSS with some sort of programming language. You cannot scrape with CSS. You will need to use a programming language like PHP to do it.

Look at the PHP function **file_get_contents** http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. Use that and pass in the full address of the page to be scraped. The function will return the entire source code. From there, you can begin massaging the data and hopefully get what you are looking for.

Try taking the string that is returned and using RegEx to break it apart, looking for patterns in the source code to return the pieces you are attempting to extract.

OR simply ask the person who's website that is for a copy of their data. I'm sure THEY have it in a nice Excel file ;-)